# How do I stop CLR Hosting?

Tags: c++, hosting, clr

I have C++ dll that injects to target program and want to load C# script from it and for this I created a wrapper that taking functions from C++ dll and hosting clr to load C# app. I am calling CLR hosting thread like this but I need to change C# script in runtime so need to do first unload this script. How can I do this ? How can I stop CLR Hosting from other function not in thread ?

```
DWORD WINAPI CreateDotNetRunTime(LPVOID lpParam)
    {
        ICLRRuntimeHost* lpRuntimeHost = NULL;
        ICLRRuntimeInfo* lpRuntimeInfo = NULL;
        ICLRMetaHost* lpMetaHost = NULL;
        FILE* file;
    
        LPWSTR AppPath = new WCHAR[_MAX_PATH];
        ::GetModuleFileNameW((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase, AppPath, _MAX_PATH);
    
        std::wstring tempPath = AppPath;
        int index = tempPath.rfind('\\');
        tempPath.erase(index, tempPath.length() - index);
        tempPath += Assembly;
    
        fopen_s(&file, Log, "a+");
    
        HRESULT hr = CLRCreateInstance(
            CLSID_CLRMetaHost, 
            IID_ICLRMetaHost, 
            (LPVOID*)&lpMetaHost
        );
    
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            fprintf(file, "Failed to create CLR instance.\n");
            fflush(file);
        }
    
        hr = lpMetaHost->GetRuntime(
            L"v4.0.30319", 
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&lpRuntimeInfo)
        );
    
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            fprintf(file, "Getting runtime failed.\n");
            fflush(file);
    
            lpMetaHost->Release();
        }
    
        BOOL fLoadable;
        hr = lpRuntimeInfo->IsLoadable(&fLoadable);
    
        if (FAILED(hr) || !fLoadable)
        {
            fprintf(file, "Runtime can't be loaded into the process.\n");
            fflush(file);
    
            lpRuntimeInfo->Release();
            lpMetaHost->Release();
        }
    
        hr = lpRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(
            CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost, 
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&lpRuntimeHost)
        );
    
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            fprintf(file, "Failed to acquire CLR runtime.\n");
            fflush(file);
    
            lpRuntimeInfo->Release();
            lpMetaHost->Release();
        }
    
        hr = lpRuntimeHost->Start();
    
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            fprintf(file, "Failed to start CLR runtime.\n");
            fflush(file);
    
            lpRuntimeHost->Release();
            lpRuntimeInfo->Release();
            lpMetaHost->Release();
        }
    
        DWORD dwRetCode = 0;
    
        hr = lpRuntimeHost->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(
            (LPWSTR)tempPath.c_str(), 
            Class,
            Method, 
            Param, 
            &dwRetCode
        );
    
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            fprintf(file, "Unable to execute assembly.\n");
            fflush(file);
    
            lpRuntimeHost->Stop();
            lpRuntimeHost->Release();
            lpRuntimeInfo->Release();
            lpMetaHost->Release();
        }
    
        fclose(file);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Calling this with:

```
CreateThread(NULL, NULL, CreateDotNetRunTime, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I fully understand your problem or specific environment, but nevertheless I venture an answer. YMMV.

You cannot completely unload the CLR.

From [ICLRRuntimeHost::Stop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/iclrruntimehost-stop-method) documentation:

```
This method does not release resources to the host, unload application domains,
or destroy threads. You must terminate the process to release these resources.
```

To fully recycle the CLR (host), it is best to launch it in a separate (child) process and communicating with it through IPC means. You would start that process from your (injected) thread.

Besides, injecting something heavyweight and dependency- and resource-laden as the CLR into "any" other process is probably not a very good idea in the first place.